# Using Jenkinsfile to Modify an existing text file during build process

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm very new to modifying jenkinsfiles and would appreciate some pointers.

I want to be able to modify an existing txt file in my repository with the detail of the changes made as part of that checkin. I've got the list of changes by using the below:

```
def getChangeLog() {
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
            def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
            for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                def file = files[k]
                echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then need to somehow be able to write this to an existing txt file before the build triggers. I also need to be able to read in the file, and confirm that the changes do exist there as well as to not insert duplicate entries.

All of this needs to be done in the Jenkinsfile somehow.

I've been able to find a lot of addons which do something like this but nothing that points to how to implement it in the Jenkinsfile itself.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The commit history can be obtained by running `git log` and analyzing output.

Comment: Are you trying to write the changelog for each builds in a file and then proceed with build? To append the changelogs for each build in a file? and then what you plan to do with the file?